# Firefox Mobile zooms in page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have been working a mobile version of my site. All seems to work perfectly fine on opera mobile and chrome mobile, until I checked my page in Firefox mobile. Firefox zooms in my page that it looks  awful. I don't know if it's CSS issue or this is how Firefox mobile renders pages. I've checked some other mobile version of famous sites and it worked perfectly fine on firefox. I badly need help with this one. Screenshot below:

**Chrome**

[image]

**Firefox**

[image]

categories is the select input
searchinput is the text input

CSS code:

```
#categories{
width: 95%;
padding: 50px;
font-size: 110%;
outline: 0;
color: #777;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
border: solid 5px #cacaca;
border-radius: 20px;
margin: 30px 0 10px 0;
background-color: #fff;
background-image: url(http://baligia.com/img/selectdown.png);
background-position: 96% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 50px;
-moz-appearance: none;
}
#searchinput{
border: solid 5px #cacaca;
border-radius: 20px;
background: #fff;
color: #42454e;
padding: 6px 8px;
width: 95%;
outline: none;
font-size: 110%;
text-align: left;
padding: 50px 130px 50px 50px;
margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}
```

Comment: Try adding more code, its just a guessing game now

Comment: umm what code? I've posted my code that shows the problem.

Comment: So you know what the problem is? Why ask the question?

Comment: Sense. I know the problem, but I don't know the solution.

Comment: So whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#categories, #searchinput {
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

Comment: Then try to replace font-size: 110% with flat value, or just set line-height to some value. What else did you tried?

Comment: font-size is not the issue. but how FF renders my page, it's zoomed in. its perfect on opera and  chrome.

Comment: @sentosa Clyde has things all figured out, I don't know why he post a question he already knows the answer too.